# Cat staring at the wall all the time

Tags: cats, behavior

My cat Annie is staring at the wall by her food bowls, so I keep changing her water every hour. She won't come out of the kitchen now. Annie and I are extremely close. I have always told her to show mommy if something is wrong and she does, but this has me baffled. I've caught her in the bathroom about three or four times lately drinking out of the toilet. I was horrified, so now I always keep the lid closed. She was sitting in there for about a week, now she's sitting in the kitchen. She has a favorite chair she wants nothing to do with. What is going on?

Comment: Any sudden behavioral change should be addressed by a veterinarian.

Comment: It's possible that she thinks she is hearing something that's coming from that area of the wall.

Comment: Well I am so pleased to announce that Annie is doing great right after I posted my concern about she came out of her strange behavior  thanks for all your help everyone Jill Franco